# How do I deal with these error messages in my newly created SwiftUI project?

Tags: swiftui, xcode13

I have just created a new SwiftUI project in Xcode 13.0, macOS Big Sur 11.6 and I getting many error messages which I don't understand.
[image: Xcode error when clicking on resume]

Comment: The name of the struct annotated with `@Main` must be the name of the App, in your case the name with the intermediate underscore characters.

Comment: I think it's something to do with my Product Name being "I Am Rich - SwiftUI". Xcode 13.0 doesn't seem to like hyphens in their product names when the project is created.

Comment: Yes, you should avoid special characters.

Comment: @Stephen501 You should try name your project with [PascalCase](https://techterms.com/definition/pascalcase) - the display name can always be different.

Answer (score 0):

I had a hyphen in my product name. Removed it and it is fine.